# Keras: concatenating model flattened output with vector

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, keras

I have a Keras model defined as such:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

After the `Flatten()` layer, I want to concatenate 2 additional features, i.e. if `Flatten()` gives me a vector of size (1, n) (`model.output_shape == (None, n)`), I want to concatenate a separate `numpy` array of size (1, 2) so `model.output_shape == (None, n+2)`. How would I go about doing this?

I think [`keras.layers.merge.Concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) is what I'm looking for here, but I don't know how to implement it. There aren't many examples online, and Keras 2.0 also uses an updated syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I played around a bit and figured it out. For anyone who's interested: this is a good use case for Keras' functional API, which always returns tensors, on which you can do tensor operations.

```
embedded_sequence = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
x = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(embedded_sequence)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)

# additional features input
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
af_input = Input(shape=(data['af_train'].shape[1],), name='af_input')
x = Concatenate()([x, af_input])

# output
main_output = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[sequence_input, af_input], outputs=main_output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: What was your sequence_input settings? In 2.0.3 I am having trouble setting it

Comment: My `sequence_input` are text indices. `sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length, ), dtype='int32', name='text_input')`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but I did [something similar](https://github.com/yohanesgultom/dmchallenge/blob/master/docker-train-2/train.py) and it worked (may not be the most efficient way though):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Flatten())

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='aux_input')
final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(Merge([model, auxiliary_input], mode='concat'))
final_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

There is also a [part of doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) that give example of having multiple inputs (and also multiple outputs) but using older API usage style.